# Use php to backup a specific database table and compress it

Tags: php, mysql

Using php is it possible to create a backup of a specific mysql database table using php.

Additionally I would like it gzipped also.

I would like it so the file was ready to be loaded directly in using the standard mysql import command i.e.

```
mysql -uuser -ppass mydb < mybackupfile.sql
```

Current solutions i am looking at involve iterating over each row and adding to a file - however this doesnt seem correct.

Comment: maybe you should use shell from php?

Answer (score 1):

You could use php to execute a mysqldump command. Like so...

exec("mysqldump -uuser -ppass --compact mydb mytable > filename.sql");

Then run another command to compress it however you like.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for this job is `mysqldump` and `gzip` combined:

```
mysqldump ...options... | gzip -9 > backup.sql.gz
```

As a note, you'll need to reverse this process before restoring:

```
gunzip -dc backup.sql.gz | mysql ...options...
```

PHP itself might be able to initiate this process but it's not an exceptionally good tool on its own. You could try [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and see if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately i need this as part of a php script